# How can I find documents in mongoDB or mongoose by checking the first element of an array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here's my schema

```
petShop: {
    name: String,
    pets: {
        dogs: [{
            color: String
            name: String
            DOB: Date
        }],
        cats: [{
            color: String
            name: String
            DOB: Date
        }],
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

Let's say,
I want to find all `petShops` that having a `white` dog and it must be the eldest dog

e.g.

`A_petShop` only has one `black` dog and one `white` dog
The `white` dog is older than the `black` dog

`B_petShop` only has one `black` dog and one `white` dog
The `black` dog is older than the `white` dog

`C_petShop` only has one `black` dog and two `white` dogs
One of the `white` dog is older than the other two dogs

So, `A_petShop` and `C_petShop` should be the query result

What should the mongoDB command or mongoose JavaScript be like?

Comment: The `dogs` are inserted into the array by ascending order (older first)...so, I think the `dogs` are sorted in the mongoDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `dogs` array is sorted with oldest first, you can query by numeric array index:

```
PetShop.find({'pets.dogs.0.color': 'white'}, function(err, petShops) {...});
```

Comment: It works!
I don't even know this trick, using `0` to indicate the element of array. I was wondering if `'pets.dogs.[0].color'` would work

but last question, what if the dogs are unsorted? (randomly arranged)

Comment: That would be more complex and would require the use of `aggregate` instead of `find`. It would be best to post that as a separate question if you need more details on that as it's non-trivial.